# Dynamic parameter for bit field on where clause in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, bit

Trying to write a SQL Server stored procedure that accepts an input parameter for a bit column that is used in the `WHERE` clause.

Based on the parameter sent to the stored procedure, I want the procedure to be able to return information. If I pass a 0 or 1 it works fine. If no parameter is sent to the stored procedure, I want all values returned.

How do I accomplish this?

```
SELECT
    field1, field2, field3
FROM
    table1
WHERE 
    field1 = @inputParm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROC TESTSP @inputParm BIT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  Select field1 ,field2 ,field3 From table1 WHERE (field1 = @inputParm OR @inputParm IS NULL)
END
```

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for catching that, but I think it's good practice to correct the original answer rather than post your own variation.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is not quite what I need.  I need to be able to return the following based on the input parameter:

Comment: This is not quite what I need.  I need to be able to return the following based on the input parameter.

• If input parameter is 1 - return where bit field = 1
• If input parameter is 0 - return where bit field = 0  
• If input parameter is NULL – return all data  

The bit field is defined as  NOT NULL

Comment: In your question you said you wanted to return all values if a null parameter value is passed into the stored procedure. If you had tried the example I provided you, you will find that it does exactly what you requested. The key is that I've set a default value on the parameter, which the OR condition accounts for. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just include another `IS NULL` condition in your `WHERE` clause like

```
WHERE field1 = @inputParm OR @inputParm IS NULL
```